# Realization of Truth table in C

Tags: avr-gcc

I want to set various clock sources in a function as per the truth table below. Basically I want to write to the TCCR0B register(Atmega328) according to the parameter I pass to setClockSource function. The image of the table and registers is given below. 
[image: Register and Modes]
I am not able to makeout how best it can be done. I thought of using enum for various modes as below.

```
    enum CLOCK_SOURCE{
      NO_CLOCK_SOURCE=0x0;
      NO_PRESCALING=0x01;
      CLK_8=0x02;
     // and so on
}
```

But the problem is in setClockSource() function, how should I write to TCCR0B register without affecting bits 3-7? Shall I first clear last 3 bits and then OR TIMER_MODE values with TCCR0B? Without clearing, I may not guarantee the correct values for last 3 bits I guess. What is the efficient way?

```
void setClockSource (enum CLOCK_SOURCE clockSource)
{
    TCCR0B&=0xF8;    // First Clear last 3 bits
    TCCR0B|=clockSource;
}
```

Do we have library functions available to set clock source? I am using Atmega studio

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
void setClockSource (CLOCK_SOURCE clockSource)
{
    TCCR0B = TCCR0B & 0xF8 | clockSource;
}
```

Thus you will keep high bits and set lower bits.